# Is Two Phase Commit suitable to ensure atomicity when sending an email?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, two-phase-commit

Let's say I need to run some queries AND send an email in an atomic way.

A typical example is for a user sign-up form, I need to create the user and send the welcome email.

I can use a transaction :

```
begin transaction
create user
if creation failed, rollback transaction, bailout
send email
if email sending failed, rollback transaction, bailout
commit transaction
```

but, in PostgreSQL, **a commit can fail** (for example when using DEFERRED constraints).

So the solution would be to use a two-phase commit :

```
begin transaction
create user
PREPARE TRANSACTION
if creation failed, rollback transaction, bailout
send email
if email sending failed, rollback transaction, bailout
COMMIT PREPARED // this one is guaranteed to work by Postgres
```

but the Postgres doc says :
[**It is unwise to leave transactions in the prepared state for a long time.**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare-transaction.html)

Moreover :

> The intended usage of the feature is that a prepared transaction will normally be committed or rolled back as soon as an external transaction manager has verified that other databases are also prepared to commit.

So,
**Is sending an email too much time ?

What problems could arise if we do so ?

What would be an acceptable timeout if it takes too long ?

Are database locks different in prepared state than in idle state (ie. before the commit) ?**

Answer (score 1):

Sending an email is not transactional.  It is possible you will never know whether it was successfully delivered or not and clearly "forever" is too long to hold onto a prepared transaction.

You will want to structure the table so that partially created users can be committed, but still known to be unconfirmed.  Like with a column indicating as much.  That way troubleshooters can actually see the partially created user to decide what to do about them.  With prepared transactions, the semi-committed rows are invisible, so no one can figure out what is going on.

To put it a somewhat different way, to use two phase commit effectively, you need to have a transaction manager.  Do you?  You didn't describe one.  Are you planning to write your own?  Do you know how much work that will be?

Comment: Sending an email is just an example, or I could use a third-party service like SendGrid and consider once we receive an HTTP 200 from SendGrid we can commit the transaction. I don't plan to write a transaction manager. I'm just wondering if TPC is ok to use with something else than querying other databases. I updated the question.

Comment: TPC sounds like the wrong tool to me as well.  having rows in a database are very useful to track down issues.  e.g. maybe have an `emails_sent` table that has `user_id`, `mail_to` (in case it changes in the future), `smtp_message_id` (so you can track it through your mail system logs / reply to it later), `date_sent`), `response_code` (e.g. from sendgrid, maybe also with a timestamp).  you'd have one transaction to create the `emails_sent` table before you send, and then another transaction to update the response_code when you get a response code back from your mail system